# Is it possible to execute uploaded .NET code in an isolated environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, appdomain, isolation

In a .NET web site I need to get code submitted by users, compile it and execute it.  But I need code to be executed in an isolated environment so that no malicious code can harm my system (for instance, no Directory.Delete("C:\Windows") should be ever executed).

Is it possible to execute code in a kind of chroot environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile and run the code in a [sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx). This is a newly created AppDomain with restricted permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [AppDomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). It's an isolated environment where applications execute. Take a look.